# Override shipping address with invalid US address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I'd like to override PayPal's shipping address with invalid US address. I did read in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/ that I just need to use `ADDROVERRIDE=1` and then override the address using `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET` (plus some other related params).

However, the documented guide is not working for me. This would work if the shipping address is located outside US. I've setup a test application and these are the codes:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def pay
    paypal_options = {
      no_shipping: true, # if you want to disable shipping information
      allow_note: false, # if you want to disable notes
      pay_on_paypal: true # if you don't plan on showing your own confirmation step
    }

    response = paypal_request.setup(
      payment_request,
      'http://localhost:3000/done',
      'http://localhost:3000/done',
      paypal_options  # Optional
    )

    redirect_to response.redirect_uri

  rescue Paypal::Exception::HttpError, Paypal::Exception::APIError => e
    puts "------- ERROR"
    puts e.response.details.map(&:long_message).join("")
  end

  def done
    @response = paypal_request.checkout!(
      params[:token],
      params[:PayerID],
      payment_request
    )
  end

  private

  def payment_request
    Paypal::Payment::Request.new(
      :description   => "Some description",    # item description
      :quantity      => 1,      # item quantity
      :amount        => 1.00,   # item value
      :custom_fields => {
        METHOD: 'SetExpressCheckout',
        ADDROVERRIDE: 1,
        REQCONFIRMSHIPPING: 0,
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTONAME" => 'Donna W. Brogan',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOCITY" => 'Oak Lawns',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOSTREET" => '4223 Flinderation Road',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOSTREET2" => '',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOSTATE" => 'IL',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE" => 'US',
        :"PAYMENTREQUEST_{n}_SHIPTOZIP" => '60453'
      }
    )
  end

  def paypal_request
    Paypal::Express::Request.new(
      :username   => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:username],
      :password   => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:password],
      :signature  => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:signature]
    )
  end
end
```

The address is invalid because there's no `Oak Lawns`, notice the extra `s`.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code
```

These are the params sent based on the debugger:

```
ADDROVERRIDE=1
&ALLOWNOTE=0
&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdone
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&NOSHIPPING=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Some+description
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Oak+Lawns
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=Donna+W.+Brogan
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=IL
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=4223+Flinderation+Road
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=60453
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdone
```

This would work well if I changed the city to `Oak Lawn` which is a valid shipping address. I'm using https://github.com/nov/paypal-express gem for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal by default verifies the US addresses with USPS format, that means when you "override" the buyer's account stored address with an invalid one, it errors out and won't let you pass. See address handling process [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_BillingShippingAddress/#id08A9BM00A5Z)

Comment: I sort of know that, but the question is, can I supply an invalid address? If it's possible, how can I do that?

Comment: For US address, no.  With "address_override" if you'd supply an invalid US address, the flow will break with error in the first place. Without "address_override", the invalid address will be stripped out and displaying the buyer's account stored address instead